# Spring cloud config /refresh crashes when spring.main.sources is set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Spent all day tracking this down...

Using spring-boot 1.3.0.RELEASE and spring-cloud-starter-config 1.1.0.M3

When I set the main class with in the application.properties file with this:

```
spring.main.sources=com.myapp.MyApplication
```

I start the app and i send a post request to http://localhost:8080/refresh i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@76d00da2] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:129) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:78) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:58) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint.addConfigFilesToEnvironment(RefreshEndpoint.java:86) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint.refresh(RefreshEndpoint.java:73) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint.invoke(RefreshEndpoint.java:140) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint.invoke(RefreshEndpoint.java:48) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter.invoke(AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter.java:53) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke(EndpointMvcAdapter.java:45) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke(GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.java:50) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

If i comment out spring.main.sources in the application.properties file and restart the application posting to the /refresh method works without errors.

Is this a bug?

Here is a sample project:

https://github.com/jmandawg/spring-cloud-config-bug.git

Run the spring-boot app and Send a post request to http://localhost:8080/refresh and watch it crash.

Comment out the one line in application.properties restart the app and send a post request to /refresh and all is well.

Comment: There isn't enough of a stack trace to tell if that's an error or just an INFO log. Please add a stack trace.

Comment: Sorry for being lazy, i updated the question with a link to a sample app that should re-create the issue.

Comment: I also update with the stacktrace.

Comment: It's a bug (please report it at spring-cloud-commons). Just to be clear though, changing the `spring.main.sources` in a running application is probably never going to work.

Comment: understood thanks,  The thing is camel-spring-boot documentation tell you explicitly to set this property...  i'm guessing it should probably be ignored by /refresh, i opened issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/79