# Can't use @Value and @Autowired with properties in Spring Cloud Configuration Server

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I have a SpringBoot 1.5.12 app using the Edgware.SR3 Spring Cloud release.
The following code:

```
@Configuration
public class HmlConfig
{
    @Value("${jms.destination.name}")
  ...
}
...
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HmlRestController
{
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
  ...
}
```

Raises the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jms.destination.name' in value "${jms.destination.name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
```

Here is my bootstrap.yml content:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: hml-core
  profiles:
    active:
      default
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888/hml
```

Going to http://localhost:8888/hml/hml-core/default correctly displays the properties. Did I miss anything ?

Comment: It seems that people here are more concerned about reformatting questions then by answering to them. I'm posting since a while on this forum and I never got a pertinent answer to my questions. However, my unanswered questions are now very well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your logs, your client can't access to the Config Server, this is why the field `jms.destination.name` can't be injected.

Add the full stacktrace of your client will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my post. Yes, I know that the client can't access to the config server, this is exactly what I'm explaining in the post. The question is why and what one needs to do such that the client could access to the config server. Do you have any idea ? If yes, please don't hesitate to enlighten me. If no, thanks again for participating. In any case, the stack trace clearly shows that the given property is not found. If I add it in a local property file, it is found. And as mentioned, the config server works correctly as I'm able to display the properties.

Comment: Adding the full stacktrace will help others to detect when failed. The first thing done by client it's to connect to the Config Server, if fails the stacktrace displays the causes (e.g not authorized, not found or something else).
Secondly, maybe you should think to add your client dependencies.
Any information can be helpful to resolve problems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have `spring.main.sources` set somewhere?

We had the excact same issue and removing that line helped us. It seems that having this in the bootstrap.yml hinders the app to connect to cloud config server. This results in missing props.

Also having `spring.main.sources` param on config server side caused a server side exception. See [Spring cloud config /refresh crashes when spring.main.sources is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600707/spring-cloud-config-refresh-crashes-when-spring-main-sources-is-set?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this post with the results of the last tests. It appears that including the maven dependencies in each of the modules solves the issue and the configuration is then found as expected.
In my original design I had a parent POM which factorized all the spring boot dependencies, as shown below:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This way the configuration client doesn't find the config server and the mentioned exception is raised. Modifying the parent POM such that to include only the dependencyManagement, as shown below:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

and moving the dependencies in the config server POM as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and in the config client as follows:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

completely solves the problem and everything works as expected. I don't have any explanation of this as including all the common dependencies in the parent POM should have exactly the same effect as including them in each individual module. In my opinion this shows some instabilities and strange behavior of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. I don't have time to dig more and to try to understand what happens. Anyway, given this kind of issues, as well as the lack of any support including on this site, we moved from Spring.
But if someone has any explanation of this, I'm still interested to know.
Kind regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Finally I could establish that having the following dependency:

    `code`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

in the parent POM raises "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder...". By simply moving it from the parent POM to the config server module POM the exception disapears and everything works as expected. Big mess !